# Slide Guitar - Pressing frets before the slide

Tags: strings, blues, slide-guitar

I'm very new to slide guitar playing, so this might sound like a stupid question. But I'm trying to learn this ["Georgia on my mind" cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0r5_qrY1J0) on a slide guitar, and I ran into a doubt.

Sometimes, like on [0:24s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0r5_qrY1J0&t=0m23s)  and on [0:28s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0r5_qrY1J0&t=0m23s) he seems to press on a fret that stands before the slide, which I didn't think would do anything (I thought I was missing something, otherwise why would he press the frets?). But while I was playing around trying to figure this part out, I realized that pressing a fret before the slide actually works because the bottleneck is only slightly touching the strings, so when you press the fret it goes a bit down and stops touching the slide.

Is that what he really does there? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: that is exactly what he is doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fretting a note before the slide bends that string down - and that means the slide doesn't touch it.  It's a fairly common technique, especially if you play slide in an open tuning.

Let's say you're tuned to open E (E-B-E-G#-B-E).  You can easily get an A major chord by placing the slide at the fifth fret, where the notes are A-E-A-C#-E-A.  But if you want to get an A *minor* chord you'll have to lower the one C# to C.

Fretting that string at the fourth fret, behind the slide, does the trick.